# tableViewのrowの削除ができません

Tags: ios, tableview, uitableview

もともとUITableViewControllerを使って問題なく動いていたテーブル画面を、UIViewController + UITableViewを使って動くように書き換えています。（UITableViewControllerだといろいろな制限が多いので。）

概ねうまく動いているのですが、ただひとつ問題が起きてスタックしております。
スワイプしてセルを削除しようとするとクラッシュしてしまうのです。
解決方法ご教示いただけたらうれしいです。

エラー内容

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1. 
 The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (8) 
 must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (9),
 plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted)
 and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
*** First throw call stack:
```

ソースコード

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        //[Parse] 該当データのIDを取得
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Item"];

        //[Parse]favoriteData配列のなかから、行数をベースに、該当データをdictionaryとして取り出す
        NSDictionary * deleteContent = [_favoriteData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        //[Parse]該当データのIDを取り出す
        NSString *itemId = [deleteContent valueForKey:@"objectId"];

        //[Local]favoriteデータ配列から該当データを削除
        [_favoriteData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        //[Local]テーブルビューからRowを削除
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        //[Parse]IDをベースにデータを削除する
        [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:itemId block:^(PFObject *deleteItem, NSError *error){

        //[Parse]オブジェクトを削除
        [deleteItem deleteInBackground];

        }];


    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: numberOfSectionsInTa‌​bleViewがreturn 2;になっていたのを1に修正することで直りました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

テーブルの更新処理を

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
...
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

で更新処理を囲う必要があるかなと思います。

（ここからEDITまでの話はなかったことに）

それでもダメなら、おそらくなのですが、タイミング問題で、

```
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

を、

```
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:itemId block:^(PFObject *deleteItem, NSError *error){
    //[Parse]オブジェクトを削除
    [deleteItem deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error){
        dispatch_async(
            dispatch_get_main_queue(),
            ^{
                 [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            }
        );
    }];
}];
```

とするとどうなるでしょうか。
Parseを使ったことがないので、このコードが正しいかは定かではありませんが、単に、データが消されてからRowを消すということが実現できるならOKだと思います。
(asyncで云々というのはそもそもダメな例でした）

---

**EDIT 1**

なんだか、混乱させてしまって申し訳ありません。上のは忘れてください...

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
     NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInSection");
     return self.data.count;
}
```

としておいて、

```
NSLog(@"endUpdates_before");
[self.tableView endUpdates];
NSLog(@"endUpdates_after");
```

を呼び出すと、

```
2014-12-12 04:22:36.534 temp[76478:2409696] endUpdates_before
2014-12-12 04:22:36.534 temp[76478:2409696] numberOfRowsInSection
2014-12-12 04:22:36.535 temp[76478:2409696] endUpdates_after
```

という出力になります。で、たぶん、numberOfRowsInSectionでParseのcountを呼んでいるのだと思うのですが、getObjectInBackgroundWithIdでblock内で削除、だと、endUpdatesが呼ばれた段階で反映されていないのかなー、と思います。numberOfRowsInSectionが返している値が正しいかどうか確かめてみてください。

呼ばれる順番とかはbegin/endの中にあれば問題なくて、endが呼ばれる瞬間までに削除が反映されたcountが帰ってきていれば、NSInternalInconsistencyExceptionが消えると思います。

Comment: さっそくコメントいただき、ありがとうございます。

いま上記のコードで実行してみたのですが、同じエラーがでてしまいました。。。

Comment: あ、素早いｗ 見落としていたので、begin/endについて追記していたのですがそれもやってみてもらえますか？

Comment: あー、もしかしたら、backgroundでデータ削除してるのが微妙なのかな...だとしたらasyncで消すのもよくわかんない感じかもしれない。全部syncにしてbegin/endでくくったらなおるのかもしれないです。混乱させてしまって申し訳ないです。

Comment: 夜遅くにお付き合い頂きありがとうございますmm
さっそく両方試してみました。
１．もともとのコードにbegin/endを追記
２．asyncにしてbegin/endを追記

が、やはり同じエラーでした。

UITableViewControllerのときはこのコードで動作していたので、それがまた不思議なんですよね。。。。

本日はそろそろ寝ます！

Comment: お役に立てなくて申し訳ないです。追記しておきました。

Comment: 今日落ち着いてソースを眺めてみました。

アドバイス頂いたとおり、numberOfRowsInSectionを見たのですが問題なし。ただ、その少し上に目をやると、numberOfSectionsInTableViewがreturn 2;になっておりました。。。。。これを１にしてみたら、ちゃんと動きました！（２にした覚えがないのですがｗ）

基礎的な間違えをしておりました。
削除がうまくいかないのでぜったいにEditの部分のコードに問題があるんだという思い込みがありましたが、視野を広くすることによって問題をみつけることができました。

アドバイスいただき、どうもありがとうございました！

Answer (score 2):

蛇足コメントかもしれませんが・・・・．

deleteRowsAtIndexPathsを呼ぶ前に，確実に，self.data.countが削除後の個数を返すようにしないといけないので，削除前に完全に同期で処理を行うのがいいと思います．

もし，非同期でやらなければならないなら．非同期処理の結果をコールバックで受け取ってから，削除アニメーションをかけるのがいいかと思いました．

Comment: コメントありがとうざいます。
解決いたしました。
もっと基本的な部分の問題でした。。。